# Curl based on poor and money-greedy binance docs

Tags: curl, binance, binance-api-client

I am trying curl to binance api.

I am basing on:

- https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/
- https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/

I have already created bunch of successful curls for example for placing limit-order in isolated futures.

Now I am just trying to change parameters/url to create new query.

Let's for example get my assets (https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#query-margin-asset-market_data).

Since it is 'MARKET_DATA' I need only API-key, no signature:

```
curl -X GET -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: MyLongPrivateKey" https://sapi.binance.com/sapi/v2/margin/allAssets
```

and I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr/>Powered by Tengine<hr><center>tengine</center>
</body>
</html>
```

When I do same curl with `-L` it redirect me to homepage...

Can any1 explain me how do I translate that #!$&*!&$%@ docs into real curl?

- https://sapi.binance.com/sapi/v1... ?
- https://sapi.binance.com/sapi/v2... ?
- https://sapi.binance.com/sapi/v3... ?
- https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/... ?
- [https://api.binance.com/api/v[someotherdigit]..](https://api.binance.com/api/v%5Bsomeotherdigit%5D..). ?

Tried various combinations, all failed..

Answer (score -1):

The correct endpoint from the document is: `GET /sapi/v1/margin/allAssets`,
and all `/sapi/*` endpoints are available under base URL `https://api.binance.com`.

So this should work:

`curl -X GET -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: MyLongPrivateKey" https://api.binance.com/sapi/v1/margin/allAssets`